# How can I inspect webview content on older Android versions? Specifically older than 4.3?

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm trying to inspect an app in Android 4.2 and 4.3, i'm able to inspect this devices using chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), but I need to test this on Webview, i didn't find a solution.
Some css are rendering different from newer versions of Android. HTML5 and CSS3 are suported in Android 4.3 webview ??

Comment: Have you a code for debug a app, if yes then put debugger points in android studio and run the app

Comment: Hi Sumit, to tell you the truth my problem is INSPECT the DOM elements in Webview, because some buttons are broking my layout. I don't know if this versions of Android are able to HTML5 or CSS3.  So I'd like to inspect it...

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no straight forward way to debug . one solution is to override the onConsoleMessage[which is used to print console statements],onJsAlert [used to show the alerts] methods of WebChromeClient attached to that webview ,get the logs and alerts , based on that upto some extent we can debug. Hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thank you Naveen Kumar, all my bugs in JS was corrected with your tip, =). 
but how can I inspect my webview to correct my css styles? In the webview some styles are rendered wrong in comparison with newer versions of Android

Comment: Hello Cristopher, Regarding css styles there is no way to debug as webview  keeps changing across different versions of the android. Really Sorry for that .if i find anything regarding debugging css i will let you know for sure. but from Lollipop onwards webview is standalone app itself . hope we will not get issues further